# Installing iMac drivers on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, drivers, boot-camp

I have installed Windows ony m iMac, and do not have OS X installed on it. Is it possible to get drivers for Mac to be installed on Windows, without going into OS X?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you installing? Also, what is the model year and screen size of your iMac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are the Boot Camp drivers for Windows. You can download them directly from the [Apple Support site](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

Normally when installing Windows on an Apple computer, you would create your partitions using Boot Camp, and have the drivers and software download using the Boot Camp Assist tool on OS X, before you install Windows, thus having it already downloaded and ready to drop on a USB key.

You can also find various support downloads and older versions of Boot Camp Drivers [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/boot%2520camp), the one I have linked you to is the latest. There are specific updates required for Windows Vista as well, if you have chosen to install an older Windows OS.